# Why include host in python socket request as well?

Tags: python, sockets

I see examples where people create the socket object from a host and port but then also send a GET request, and include the Host header inside the http request.

```
import socket

HOST = 'daring.cwi.nl'
PORT = 80

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\nHost: daring.cwi.nl")
    data = s.recv(1024)
print('Received', repr(data))
```

Why do we need to provide the host once to create socket object and again to send the request?

Comment: The socket itself is layer 4 (transport) and then your application rides on top of it. And the HTTP is an application layer protocol. The Host in socket in order to find IP, and the Host in HTTP tells the webserver which virtual host to use.

Comment: You needn't, you can change it into `s.sendall("HAHAHA")`.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary as it is just a normal tcp connection.

Comment: How would I send a get request with only parameters in sockets in python? Assuming I created the socket in this fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you are using just a normal tcp connection, you can send anything you want, you can `s.sendall("HAHAHA")`.

Second, In your code, it is simulating a `Get` http request. To send parameters, you just need to concatenate them after url. `/?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2`.

Finally, why we need to include `Host` again? Assume you are sending this request to a load-balance server, the application server cannot get real `Host` without you explicitly sending it.

Comment: This is not primarily a requirement of a load balancer. The header is also needed if you have a server which hosts several domains on the same IP address - which is very common especially for the cheaper hosting solutions.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Anyway, it's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

The `Host` header is required by the HTTP standard (at least version 1.1), i.e. the standard which defines the protocol spoken with a web server. The reason for this is that you can have multiple domains share the same IP address and thus the web server somehow needs to find out which of the domains you want to access. Since the lower layer (i.e. TCP) does not contain this information but only the IP address you need to provide this information at the application layer (i.e. HTTP).

As for using the hostname inside the `connect`: This is actually not needed and you could also provide the IP address there. All what it does when providing the hostname and not the IP is to lookup the IP address for the host and connect to this.